# Переписать sql запрос в синтаксисе linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Нужно `Sql` запрос переписать в синтаксисе `linq`:

```
select
  sum(hour)
from
  Workings
having
  p.UserId = work.UserId
  and p.Year= work.Year
group by  UserId, Year
```

Погуглил, и примерно написал запрос который нужен, но я его не понимаю.

```
int sum = db2.Workings
             .GroupBy(p => p.UserId == work.UserId && p.Year== work.Year)
             .Select(p => new { Summa= p.Sum(b => b.Hours), Name = p.UserId})
```

Как переписать правильно?

Comment: _"int sum = db2.Workings.GroupBy(..."_ -- `int` замените на `var`. а что надо сделать? вывести данные из запроса на страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых это не запрос в MVC, а linq запрос. Насколько я понял что именно необходимо, запрос должен быть таким.

сумма для конкретного UserId

```
int summ = db2.Workings.Where(p => p.UserId == work.UserId && p.Year==
work.Year).Sum(sumHours=>sumHours.Hours);
```

Ну а если так необходима группировка то

```
var sum = db2.Workings.GroupBy(p => p.UserId == work.UserId && p.Year== work.Year).Where(k=>k.key==true).Select(ob=>new{ID=work.UserId,HoursSum=
>ob.Sum(p=>p.Hours)});
```